# Where can I find the details about the argument to be passed to a passport.js Strategy?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am not getting the exact details about which arguments need to be passed in the Passport Strategy. It would be very helpful if someone points me to the documentation.

For example:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done){}));
```

Here the callback function of the `LocalStrategy` requires `username`, `password` and `done`.

I just want to know where it is documented and also for `BearerStrategy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create your own strategy you will want to extend passport-strategy. It can be found here with documentation: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-strategy

The parameters will be up to you to define depending on the needs of your custom strategy.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know where it is document

[Passport local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) <---this shows which arguments need to be passed to configure passport

> The local authentication strategy authenticates users using a username
>   and password. The strategy requires a verify callback, which accepts
>   these credentials and calls done providing a user.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

You compare the username from the name attribute of your form to the one in your database. I think you were asking for documentation so I provided the link above